# Iterating an array of objects in js/node10 and accessing properties of each item

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to iterate through an object array that looks like the following using javascript w/ node.js 10.

I have tried the following and it is saying it isn't iterable:

```js
const persons = [
 { id: 1, name: 'Alice', age: null },
 { id: 2, name: 'Mike', age: 52 },
 { id: 3, name: 'Carol', age: 50 }
]

for(let person of persons) {
 console.log(person.id);
}
```

Here is how I am retreiving persons using https://github.com/jeremydaly/data-api-client:

```
  let persons = await dataApi.query(
    `SELECT id, name, age
     FROM person`);
```

Comment: use javascript map (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)[link]

Comment: What have you done till now?

Comment: Tried on an online node 10 repl - cannot reproduce (at least not the error described, of it not being iterable). Apart from assigning your array to a variable, and the typo of `channel.id` vs `person.id`, this code works.

Comment: I updated this post at the bottom I am using data-api-client to make a call. I am working with a lambda function in AWS so unable to utilize console.log right now. I can confirm that the persons are being returned and set because I was able to see JSON.stringify(persons). Still can't get it to work... I am pretty sure persons is nothing more then an object array.

Comment: Something is wrong, and whatever it is, you are not showing. If `persons` really was what you think it is, the code would work.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it all in two nested loops:

```
for(let person of persons) {
  for(let key in person){
    if(person.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      console.log(person[key]);
    }
  }
}
```